# DropDownList doesn't pass additional parameter

Tags: drop-down-menu

I would like to pass a number selected from DropDownlist to a GET Create method in other Controller. It looks like:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Details(int? id, string error)
    {
        {...}
        var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100);
        ViewBag.Quantity = numbers.Select(i => new SelectListItem { Value = i.ToString(), Text = i + "%" });
        return View(viewModel);
    }

public ActionResult Create(int ID, int quantity)
        {
            {...}
        }
```

Details View looks like:

```
<div>
    @if (Model.ItemRent.Zatwierdzony == false)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ItemRentLists", new { ID = @Model.ItemRent.ItemRentID }, FormMethod.Get))
        {
            @Html.DropDownList("quantity", new SelectList(ViewBag.Quantity, "Text", "Value"))
            <input type="submit" value="Dodaj przedmioty"/>
        }
    }
</div>
```

DropDownList doesn't pass a Value to "quantity" parameter in Create method, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

OK I changed `@Html.DropDownList("quantity", ViewBag.Quantity as SelectList)` and now it works as it should work.